# How to pass lookup values from one object to another object's lookup field using trigger

Tags: trigger

here is my code in which i am trying to pass lookup values and owner so that i can create an order record. but i m facing error for contractor lookup field-- "

> Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Id to Contract at line
>   11 column 15"

and for owner--

> "Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from User to Name at line 12
>   column 16"

Code of class in which i have written a trigger

```
public class order_Creation
{
    public static void osCreated(List<Opportunity> op)
    {
       List <Order> orderToInsert = new List <Order>(); 
      for(Opportunity o : op){        
         if(o.StageName == 'Closed Won'){      
               Order v = new Order();         
               v.Account = o.Account; 
               v.EffectiveDate = System.today();
              v.Contract = o.Contract_Number__c; 
               v.Owner = o.owner; 
               orderToInsert.add(v);
         }
       }



      try {
          insert orderToInsert;    
      } 
      catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
          system.debug (e);
      }


   }

}
```

Comment: `v.Contract = o.Contract_Number__c;` instead use `v.ContractId = o.Contract_Number__c; `

Comment: thanks it works, but what about owner

Comment: It will be ownerId

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
v.Contract = o.Contract_Number__c; 
 v.Owner = o.owner;
```

to

```
 v.ContractId = o.Contract_Number__c; 
 v.OwnerId = o.ownerId;
```

Always check field API name..

Comment: i have tried this its working no error is there but its not creating contract record, have given all required values

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM don't use `try catch` and check.. you will get error then